# Apache IVY to Maven : Bug Excluding Artifacts?

Tags: ant, pom.xml, ivy, nexus

I think there is a bug translating from ivy to maven "makepom" when the excursion set of artifacts:

For example, this IVY xml :

```
<dependency org="org.apache.xmlgraphics" name="fop" rev="1.0" transitive="true" conf="compile->master">     
            <exclude org="org.apache.xmlgraphics" name="batik-awt-util"  />     
</dependency>
```

Is translated this way to POM

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
<artifactId>fop</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
   <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
   <artifactId>*</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

As seen, rather than exclude the artifact  "batik-awt-util" , all artifacts (*) are excluded !!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to exclude by module:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.xmlgraphics" name="fop" rev="1.0" transitive="false" conf="compile->master">           
    <exclude org="org.apache.xmlgraphics" module="batik-awt-util" />          
</dependency>
```

look at how the exclude is defined:

```
<exclude org="org.apache.xmlgraphics" module="batik-awt-util" />
```

instead of:

```
<exclude org="org.apache.xmlgraphics" name="batik-awt-util" />
```

Comment: Despite of this something is wrong with FOP dependency management. The POM is ok....but it's imposible to exclude batik!!   I probed the same exclusions with other libraries and works fine......